# Suggestion to refactor code into simple way -React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks, react-redux

I have multiple  with the same class name and method with different parameter
i want to refactor the below code to a simpler way any suggestion would be helpful.

```
<table class="greyGridTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>AA</td>
      <td className = 'table-container'>{formatDate(someMethod1(param1,a)}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>BB</td>
      <td className = 'table-container'>{formatDate(someMethod1(param1,b)}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>CC</td>
      <td className = 'table-container'>{formatDate(someMethod1(param1,c)}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to refactor the code with the same component.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hope this would be helpful. thanks

```
export const TableItems = ({data}) => {
  return (
    <>
      {data.map(item => (
        <tr>
          <td>{item.name}</td>
          <td className='table-container'> {item?.symbol} {formatDate(someMethod1(param1,a)}</td>
        </tr>
      ))}
    </>
  )
}


const data = [
  {
    name: AA,
  },
  {
    name: BB,
  },
  {
    name: CC,
    symbol: '£'
  }
]

<table class="greyGridTable">
  <tbody>
    <TableItems data={data} />
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: can we create component and return only <td>?

Comment: I have updated the code, can you please check. :)

Comment: what if I need to add some £  symbol to CC objectHow are we going to add  them if we loop through

Comment: yes, you can add the symbol in CC object like `symbol: £` and if you are not adding the symbol to other objects, So where you are printing the symbol, there you need to make the condition like `<td>{d?.symbol}</td>`

Comment: Can you please update the answer we are iterating through all the data but I need £ only for CC before the value

Comment: It should not be new td should  be before formatdate just consider format currency instead of formatdate

Comment: I am not able to pass array of objects as parameter  inside tableitems({data},abc)  ABC is a prop

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245965/discussion-between-ahmad-faraz-and-r9102).

Answer (score 2):

Try to use an array instead. Having reusable components in an array is easy to maintain, expand and read. Definitely a good practice.

```
let tableItems = [{name:"AA",date:new Date()},.....]

return (

<table class="greyGridTable">
  <tbody>
    {tableItems.map((item,index)=>{
     return(
       <tr>
         <td>{item.date}</td>
         <td className = 'table-container'>{item.date}</td>
       </tr>
     )
    })}
  </tbody>
</table>

)
```

Comment: You can also extract and the className in a variable also, if you want conditional rendering

Comment: can we create component and return only <td>?

Comment: formatDate is a common function i don't want to use new date()

Comment: You can extract the return of the map function into a separate component. It would be even better to be honest. Also, yes, you can use formatDate(), and you can add as many properties as you can

Comment: here is a nice article you can refer to https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-list-component/. Having more smaller components is generally better than having fewer bigger components. Just try not to overuse this practice if it's not necessary